# How to work with upcoming events without year

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, date

I have a React native application with events where I have event dates in ISO format. I need to work with events on a yearly repeating basis. Events include dates like birthdays and also yearly events. I need to display upcoming events for the rest of the current year then display events for the next year. How to work with events without a year and sort by current date?

```
events.sort((a, b) => {
    const today = new Date();
    const currentYear = today.getFullYear();
    const dateA = new Date(a.date);
    dateA.setFullYear(currentYear);
    const dateB = new Date(b.date);
    dateB.setFullYear(currentYear);
    return dateA - dateB;
})
.filter(event => {
    const today = new Date();
    const currentYear = today.getFullYear();
    const eventDate = new Date(event.date);
    eventDate.setFullYear(currentYear);
    return eventDate > today;
})
.splice(0, 5)
.map(event => {
...
```

Comment: You really haven't specifically identified where you are stuck or what is or isn;t working as expected in the code shown. Your objective is still rather loosely defined also. Perhaps you want to loop through the events and create date entries for current year and next year ? You could easily do that before the sort then the sort would be just `a-b`

Comment: Also please provide some sample data and expected results as per [mre]

Comment: With repeating events, it's typical to specify a start date and a rule for repetition. So for birthday it might be `birthdate: 1970-01-01, rule: 'annual'}`. For others the rule might be "first Monday of month", "last day of quarter", etc. You might want to encode the rules so they're easier to parse and process.

Comment: @charlietfl For example, event dates are in the format:  
` 
1995-12-22T12:32:00.000Z,
2014-12-27T23:00:00.000Z,
2021-01-20T00:00:00.000Z,
1992-02-03T21:02:00.000Z,
2016-02-21T17:23:00.000Z
`

Today is 20.12. and I want to display events in the following order: 22.12, 28.12, 20.1., 3.2., 21.2. ..